# Using powershell to list managed metadata terms

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata

I'd like to gather statistics on managed metadata use. Instead of quering the content by the terms (one by one), I'd like to run through selected lists, listing the used terms per item. Is this possible using Powershell? I have only found examples of the former strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible: Yes
Is is practical: Probably not

If you really want the the process will be:

```
Loop thought all WebApplications
  Loop though all site collections
    Loop through all sites
      Loop through all lists
        Find fields which are TaxonomyFieldType or TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti
        Loop through all items
          Loop through values of fields found above
            Increment counters
```